# Execute a process in the current pane, redirecting stdio to/from the pane

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux

GNU Screen has a command called `exec` that will launch a subprocess and optionally let you do things with its file descriptors, including tying them in your window. I frequently use `:exec !! sx -b /tmp/file` to send a file over a serial link using the xmodem protocol.

I'm looking for the same functionality in tmux so I can move away from screen without having to use minicom's (or picocom's, etc,) function for sending files.

Answer (score 1):

Run tmux

```
tmux
```

Go to the command mode in your tmux session:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> then <kbd>:</kbd>

Then split a new window with a command associated.

```
split-window -d 'exec sx -b /tmp/file'
```

Option -d is optional, it is to detach from the new pane and to return to the first. That will works with new-window command too.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> then <kbd>o</kbd> will switch from one pane to the other.

I didn't tested it with **sx**, but it worked with `exec top`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at tmux's respawn-window command and http://hyperpolyglot.org/multiplexers

Comment: I don't know how I could use that to accomplish my goal. I want to dump stdout from a command into a window, and dump the window's output into stdin of the command.